# Rails loop thru attachments and show the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have implemented a basic search and I would like to show each result aligned with an image.
I'm using the `carrierwave gem` on my app and trying loop thru attachments in order to show only the first one as thumbnail.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-thumbnail" style="display: inline-block;">
    <% if @items.present? %>
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
        <% item.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
            <%= image_tag attachment.url(:mini).first unless attachment.blank? %>
            <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
 </div>

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "description"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.json "attachments"
end
```

But unfortunately the image does not show, no errors etheir just a blank thumbnail. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Are you using `paperclip` or another gem? If you are, please specify it in your question and put it in the tags. Also, can you show your item model definition (the part related to the attachment)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @André Guimarães Sakata, i have updated my question with more info

Comment: I'm not familiar with carrierwave, but at first blush I don't see a need to iterate over attachments. Why aren't lines 5-8 something like `item.attachments.find(&:present?)&.url(:mini)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer, you iterate over `attachments` and add an index to the iteration. But the only purpose of the iteration is to choose an attachment whose index == 0. A much easier way to express the same thing is just to retrieve the attachment at index 0 directly using `attachments[0]`. To be more Ruby-idiomatic, we can use `attachments.first`.

So we can do away with the inner iteration entirely. All we need is to check if `@items` is present, then iterate over `items`, pick the first attachment of each, and retrieve the url.

Here's a simplified version:

```
<% if @items.present? %>
    <% @items.each do |item|%>
         <%= image_tag item.attachments.first.url(:mini) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this will fail (your code will too) if any item has no attachments. You may want to guard against this by using Ruby's safe-navigation operator (which works in Ruby 2.3+). You can replace the third line with this:

```
         <%= image_tag item.attachments.first&.url(:mini) %>
# This prevents error if `.first` return nil ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @moveson! Your solution is working too!